# Apple Shortcuts: Get out of loops

Tags: sirishortcuts

I am trying to build a shortcut to tell me how many bikes are at my Divvy station

How can I get out of the "Repeat with each item in..." function once the right station is found?

Here is my "code":

```
 - URL: [https://gbfs.divvybikes.com/gbfs/en/station_status.json][1]
 - Get contents of URL
 - Get Value for data in URL
 - Get Value for stations in Dictionary Value
 - Repeat with each item in Dictionary Value
    - Get Value for legacy_id in Repeat Item //this is the station id
    - If Dictionary Value is 74 //the station I am looking for
      - Get Value for num_bikes_available in Repeat Item //returns number of bikes available
      - Speak Dictionary Value

    // How can I get out here?
    - End If
  - End Repeat


  [1]: https://gbfs.divvybikes.com/gbfs/en/station_status.json
```